# How to make exceptions to Me.Controls.OfType

Tags: vb.net

I'd like to make this method more general and can accept exceptions to the rule instead of having to type every TextBox manually every time an exception is made.

I use this method to check if any of the TextBoxes are empty. I'd like to make the middle initial and phone number optional but I cant seem to get the right results.

If possible I'd love to be able to pass the exceptions as parameters instead so I can just put this in a module.

Edit: It's a windows application

```vb
 Private Function CheckIfEmpty() As Boolean

    'Checks if All textboxes are empty

    Dim empty = Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().Where(Function(txt) txt.Text.Trim.Length = 0)

    If empty.Any Then
        'Makes Middle Initial and Phone number optional
        If txtMiddleInitial.Text.Trim = "" Or txtPhoneNum.Text.Trim = "" Then
            MsgBoxSetMsg(" Please fill up all fields")
            CheckIfEmpty = True
        End If
    Else
        CheckIfEmpty = False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and remove `c#` tag.  Moreover, it is windows application or web application? Try to tag that in question too. Thanks

Comment: Consider using the `Tag` property of the TextBoxes to indicate whether or not they are optional. Then your `CheckIfEmpty` function only needs to check the `Tag`.

Comment: To take @Blackwood's suggestion a step further, you can create your own custom control that inherits `TextBox` and you can add your own `Boolean` property that you can use to determine whether the field is mandatory or not.  You can then use that control instead of the standard `TextBox` on your form.  Making the change to an existing form is a simple matter of editing the designer code file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question as asked:

```
Private Function CheckIfEmpty(ParamArray exemptions As TextBox()) As Boolean

    'Checks if All textboxes are empty

    Dim empty = Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().Where(Function(txt) txt.Text.Trim.Length = 0 AndAlso Not exceptions.Contains(txt))

    If empty.Any Then
        MsgBoxSetMsg(" Please fill up all fields")
        CheckIfEmpty = True
    Else
        CheckIfEmpty = False
    End If
End Function
```

You could then call it like so:

```
Dim validated = CheckIfEmpty(txtMiddleInitial, txtPhoneNum)
```

Comment: Note that this code still uses `Me.Controls` as your original code did.  That will not transfer directly to a module, but that is a separate issue so off-topic for this thread.

Comment: This is exactly what I asked for, thank you.

@jmcilhinney can you elaborate on that? I use the method on multiple forms but I usually just copy and paste the method. Sorry I am a vb newbie.

Answer (score 0):

```
Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().Where(Function(t) t.Name <> "txtMiddileInitial" AndAlso t.Name <> "txtPhoneNum")
```

Answer (score 0):

Per Blackwood's comment, here is code to check the `.Tag` property. If it contains a "O" (for "Optional") then it does not need to be filled in:

```
Function CheckForm() As String 'returns an error message if form not filled in properly
  For Each ctl As Control In Me.Controls
    Dim strTag As String = ""
    If ctl.Tag IsNot Nothing Then strTag = ctl.Tag.ToString
    If TypeOf ctl Is TextBox Then
      Dim txt As TextBox = DirectCast(ctl, TextBox)
      If txt.Text = "" And Not strTag.Contains("O") Then
        Return "Please fill in all fields"
      End If
    ElseIf TypeOf ctl Is ListBox Then
      '...etc...
    End If
  Next ctl
  Return "" 'no error 
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Function CheckIfEmpty(except As TextBox()) As Boolean

    CheckIfEmpty = _
        Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)() _
            .Where(Function(txt) Not except.Contains(txt)) _
            .Where(Function(txt) txt.Text.Trim.Length = 0) _
            .Any()

    If CheckIfEmpty Then
        MsgBoxSetMsg(" Please fill up all fields")
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: That's still hard-coding the exemptions in the method. The question specifically asked that they be passed as arguments.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - Fixed it. Cheers for that.

Comment: Fixed your C# syntax. :-)

Comment: @jmcilhinney - Much appreciated. Habits are hard to break.